# Handle Callbacks in Socket.io android client v1.4

Tags: java, android, sockets, callback, socket.io

I am not able to find any doc on how to properly handle Ack's and Events in the latest `Socket.io` (*v1.4.3*). All existing articles/question refer to older versions, especially the `IOCallback` class. But that class is not present on the latest version.

All I managed to find out till now is this :

**To get Callbacks for `Socket` Events**:

```
mSocket.connect();

mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        //What to do here
    }
})
```

1. How do I handle the `(Object... args)`. A little code example would be great.
2. There seems to be more than a dozen events, do I have to handle all that separately? Or what is a good minimum set of events that I can implement to be informed about the connection?

**To get callbacks for individual `emit` events** :

```
mSocket.emit("payload", jsObj.toString(), new Ack() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        //TODO process ACK
    }
});
```

1. Again, how am I supposed to process the `(Object... args)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well. I finally figured that out on my own.

**How do I handle the `(Object... args)` on the *EVENT_CONNECT* listener's `call`method?**

I haven't yet figured that out. But I'm lookin.

**What is a good minimum set of events that I can implement to be informed about the connection**

These three methods would be sufficient :

> *connect* : Fired upon a successful connection.
>   *connect_error* : Fired upon a connection error.
>   *connect_timeout* : Fired upon a connection timeout.

Source : [Socket.io Docs](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#manager%28url:string,-opts:object%29)

**how am I supposed to process the `(Object... args)` on an emit acknowledgement?**

So I was digging through the docs and found [this](http://socket.io/docs/#sending-and-getting-data-%28acknowledgements%29) :

> *Server (app.js)*
>
> ```
> var io = require('socket.io')(80);
>   io.on('connection', function (socket) {
>     socket.on('ferret', function (name, fn) {
>       fn('woot');
>     });
>   });
> ```
>
> *Client*
>
> ```
> socket.on('connect', function () { // TIP: you can avoid listening on `connect` and listen on events directly too!
>     socket.emit('ferret', 'tobi', function (data) {
>       console.log(data); // data will be 'woot'
>     });
>   });
> ```

So the args will be whatever the server sent as parameter into the callback. So this is how you would write `Java` client code for the above server code :

```
public void call(Object... args) {
  String response = (String)args[0]; //this will be woot
}
```

The param can also be JSON, or any of the [supported datatypes](http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/#emitting-events) in socket.io :

> we send a string but you can do JSON data too with the org.json package, and even binary data is supported as well!

Comment: Cheers .Now move ahead .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya you are welcome to improve the answer. there is so little help on `socket.io` available on SO.

Answer (score 2):

No In Android its works like this

payload can be of JSONOBJECT/JSONArray

```
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Ack

socket.emit("EVENT_NAME", payload, Ack {
                    val ackData = it[0]
                    Logger.e(TAG, "ackData $ackData")

                })
```

server side

```
  socket.on('EVENT_NAME', (payload, callback) => {
   callback("success");
});
```